# Optimizing performance of morphological processing

Tags: java, image-processing, face-detection, mathematical-morphology, image-morphology

I am working in face detection using the YCbCr color space. When I apply it on a human face, there are gaps that denote the nose, eye and mouth and the resultant patch looks like **(a)**.  In order to remove these gaps, I apply a morphological dilation operation and I get the resulting image shown in **(b)** but my requirement is to get patch like it is shown in **(c)**.  This means that I want to remove the outer contours from the processed patch.

[image]

Can anyone please suggest that how can I remove these outer contours?

Comment: Since you're dealing in image processing, it's hard to visualize this without an actual image.  Your post is making it sound like you're referring to an image but it's not present in your post.  Can you please edit your post accordingly?

Comment: Can you upload image (a) by itself individually?

Comment: You probably want to erode first and then dilate.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions for you, though it's hard to verify this without the actual raw images themselves.  Try one of these and see if you get something meaningful.

---

## Method #1 - Use `imfill` followed by `imopen`

One suggestion I have is to use [`imfill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) to fill in any of the holes in the image, followed by a call to `imopen` to perform morphological opening (i.e. erosion followed by dilation as alluded to by user Paul R).  Opening (via [`imopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html)) removes any small isolated regions in the image subject to the desired structuring element.

Assuming your image is stored in the variable `BW`, something like this may work:

```
BW2 = imfill(BW, 'holes');
se = strel('square', 5);
BW2 = imopen(BW2, se);
```

`BW2` is the final image.

## Method #2 - Use `bwareaopen` followed by `imdilate`

I can also suggest using the function [`bwareaopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html) which removes objects whose areas fall under a certain amount.  Try something small like an area of 80 pixels to remove those isolated areas, then use the dilation (`imdilate`) command that you alluded to in your post:

```
BW2 = bwareaopen(BW, 80);
%// Place your code for dilation here using BW2
```

## Method #3 - Open your image with `imopen` then perform `imdilate`

One final thing I can suggest is to open your image first to remove the spurious small pixel areas, then perform your dilation code as you suggested:

```
se = strel('square', 5);
BW2 = imopen(BW, se);
%// Place your code for dilation here using BW2
```

Comment: sir, will I get similar built in functions in java-cv (opencv java) ?

Comment: You tagged your post with **MATLAB**, not Java.  `bwareaopen` and perhaps `imfill` are probably not in JavaCV but method #3 is probably the most suitable for you with what I know of JavaCV.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following steps:

1. Fill holes => [result](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/Result_FillHole.png). It fills all the holes into the face.
2. Opening (erosion + dilation) => [result](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/Result_Open.png). It erases all the small patterns outside the shape.

Even better: you replace the step 2 by an "opening by reconstruction" which is an erosion followed by a geodesic reconstruction. This operation does not modify the main pattern. See [the result](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/Result_Opening.png).

All these operations should be available in OpenCV or ImageJ.